# How to make a sbt task use a specific configuration scope?

Tags: scala, build, scope, sbt

I have a task `lazy val task = TaskKey[Unit]` that takes a `lazy val setting = SettingKey[String]` as input. I also have three different, independent config scopes (`config("dev")`, `config("stage")`, `config("prod")`) and a `build.sbt` file that specifies different values for `setting` for each of the config scopes (`setting in stage := "foo"` ... ).

I expected that calling `task` using the config scope prefix would make the task use the values from the respective config scope (e.g.  `>dev:task` would make the task use the `setting` values from `dev`, using command `>stage:task` would make the task use the `setting` values from `stage`, ...). However, this does not seem to work.

How can I force `task` to use the settings from a specific config scope?

build.sbt:

```
setting := "default setting"

setting in stage := "stage setting"

setting in prod  := "prod setting"
```

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TaskBuild extends Build {
  val setting = SettingKey[String]("setting", "a simple string setting")

  val task = TaskKey[Unit]("task", "a simple task experiment")

  val taskTask = task <<= setting map { s: String =>
    println("Setting is: " + s)
  }

  lazy val dev = config("dev") describedAs("dev environment settings")
  lazy val stage = config("stage") describedAs("stage environment settings")
  lazy val prod = config("prod") describedAs("prod environment settings")

  lazy val root = Project(
    "project",
     file("."),
     settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(taskTask)
  )
  .configs(dev, stage, prod)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write something like

```
val devTaskSetting = task <<= setting in dev map { s: String =>
   println("Setting in Dev is: " + s)
}
```

You can also define separate task keys, like this

```
val devTask   = TaskKey[Unit]("task", "a simple task experiment") in dev
val stageTask = TaskKey[Unit]("task", "a simple task experiment") in stage
```

Comment: So it isn't possible to decide at runtime what config scope to use, one has to define a task for each possible config?

Comment: I'm not sure. But you can use the _same function_ (task body) for `map` multiple times. Not an expert here, so maybe wait for more comments.

Comment: Well, it's a start! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 7):

As discussed in [How can i make an SBT key see settings for the current configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437443/how-can-i-make-an-sbt-key-see-settings-for-the-current-configuration/17479710#17479710), you can probably use `inConfig` as follows.

Change this:

```
settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(taskTask)
```

to this:

```
settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++
  Seq(taskTask) ++
  inConfig(dev)(Seq(taskTask)) ++
  inConfig(stage)(Seq(taskTask)) ++
  inConfig(prod)(Seq(taskTask))
```

and voilà:

```
$ sbt
> task
Setting is: default setting
> dev:task
Setting is: default setting
> stage:task
Setting is: stage setting
> prod:task
Setting is: prod setting
```

If you're interested in digging deeper, `inConfig` is defined in `sbt.Project` ( http://harrah.github.io/xsbt/latest/api/index.html#sbt.Project$ ) as a function to "copy a subgraph of tasks/settings into different scopes" (as @MarkHarrah describes it). Also, take a look at http://eed3si9n.com/sbt-010-guide and scroll down to "changing the scopes" where the author explains how `inConfig(conf)(ss)` "scopes the settings ss in to conf only when it isn't scoped yet to a configuration".